# Where did my shield go? How can I get a new one?

Tags: zelda-link-to-the-past

I have just finished the second dungeon in the dark world, and as I was leaving the dungeon I noticed I no longer appear to have a shield? I had recently upgraded this to a fire shield and I definitely entered the dungeon with one equipped so where did it go?

[image]

[image]

Where did my shield go? How can I get a new one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was most likely eaten by an enemy. You are going to need to buy another.

The enemy that took it is probably the flower like creature that sticks its tongue out while it attacks, called a [Pikit](http://zeldawiki.org/Pikit).

If you are playing the Gameboy Advance version, it could also be a [Like-Like](http://zeldawiki.org/Like_Like) that took your shield.

Comment: Good god I hate those things. They always die first, no matter what else is on-screen.

Comment: It's been a while, but can't you just kill the Pikit and then you can collect your shield again? Unless, of course, you left the screen in the meanwhile, then it's gone

Comment: Killing a Pikit returns only the last item it consumed of yours. So, if it eats your shield and then some rupees, you won't get your shield back.

Answer (score 4):

I'm still not sure where my shield went, but I found somewhere you can buy a new basic shield from; in the Dark World in the same location as the Magic Shop in the Light World, there is a general store which sells a shield:

[image]

[image]

From here you can purchase another shield, and then go through the process of upgrading it again.